# VSCode: SFTP upload file not work for one folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp

I use vscode and sftp extension

This extension work fine, but for one of folders I get error:

```
/lib: Permission denied

at Socket.p (/Users/mohammad/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/dist/extension.js:70:114046)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:276:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17) 
[07-19 09:36:11] [debug] > NOOP
```

I check folder and files permision and all permision is 777

Comment: Are you sure? `\lib` should not be 777. If it were, anyone could rewrite public libraries.

Comment: @mankowitz I change it to 777 for test and upload. but not work for me for this folder

Comment: can you `ls -al /lib`?

Comment: @mankowitz i get this result : total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  2 mohammad  staff   64 Jul 19 09:29 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 18 mohammad  staff  576 Jul 19 09:29 ..